# SQL unique query -- need help

Tags: sql, unique

Need some help with what is probably a pretty basic SQL query. I'm trying to select the number of unique records that match a specific where clause.

Essentially, I'm looking to find the number of unique users that logged in between date x and y. If a user logged in more than once between those dates, it would need to only count once.

The data looks something like this:

```
id | user_id | lastLogin
1  | 100     | 2010-06-23 10:00:00
2  | 101     | 2010-06-23 10:05:00
3  | 100     | 2010-06-23 11:00:00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), user_id, MAX(lastLogin)
FROM login_table
WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY user_id
```

This will get you a login count, and the last login date as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from login_table
where lastlogin between @startdatetime and @enddatetime
```

Comment: Note that for very large tables and Microsoft SQL Server it is faster to execute dynamic SQL with literals created using the date variables because SQL is slower comparing against the variables.

In other words "WHERE lastLogin BETWEEN @var1 AND @var2" is much slower than "WHERE lastLogin BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-05-01'" even if the variables are set to the same dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Distinct SQL operator.

Example

```
select distinct user_id from UsersLoggedIn where lastLogin >= '2010-06-23 10:00:00' and lastLogin <= '2010-06-23 11:00:00'
```

You could wrap that in a count to get the count of users.

```
select count(*) from (select distinct user_id from UsersLoggedIn where lastLogin >= '2010-06-23 10:00:00' and lastLogin <= '2010-06-23 11:00:00') x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table WHERE lastLogin BETWEEN ....
```